# how to compress the file created from Spring AbstractExcelView

Tags: spring, download, compression

I am using spring AbstractExcelView to create an excel file in my application.

The problem i am facing is that the resultant excel file is becoming too large.

Is there a way to compress the file which is generated from the AbstractExcelView and download it as a zip file

The excel which is generated is close to 15 MB, but when i manually zip the file it is 700KB, so there is a huge difference.

Any tips for compressing the output from the AbstractExcelView in spring

Comment: The way i solved this is by using the AbstractExcelView, But got the data into the contorller and used java.util.zip to compress the file